# Check if the sequence of function converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Which of the following sequencens of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ is convergent in $\mathcal{C}(0,2\pi)$:

a) $f_n=\sin^n(x)$

b) $f_n=\sin(\frac{x}{n})$

How do I check convergence if they are not so typical power series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $f_n(\frac{3\pi}{2})=(-1)^n$, so $f_n$ does not converge pointwise.

b)In general we have $|\sin(x)|\leq x$ on $\mathbb{R}$. So $\forall x \in [0,2\pi],|\sin(\frac{x}{n})|\leq\frac{x}{n}\leq \frac{2\pi}{n}$. So we have a uniforme convergence of $f_n$ towards $f=0$. So $f_n$ converges also pointwise.